# Fitting a hyperbola to a set of data points

Tags: conic-sections, least-squares

I would like to fit a hyperbola to a set of data points. In the post at this link: [How can I fit a set of data points to a hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482202/how-can-i-fit-a-set-of-data-points-to-a-hyperbola-a-square-root-function-or-a-l) Claude Leibovici rearranges the equation I would like to use to give it a linear form suitable for least squares regression (or an initial estimate, at least).

He starts with:
$$y=\frac{k}{b+x}+c$$
And then sets:
$$t_i=\frac{1}{b+x_i}$$
To give:
$$y=b t+b$$
I'm afraid I don't understand how this set of equations works - what happened to the rest of the parameters?

I would like to use the first equation in a linear form so that I can obtain a good initial estimate of $k$, $b$ and $c$.

Thanks.

Comment: That last line doesn't make much sense. Are you sure it's not $y=kt+c$?

Comment: I am sorry !! There were typo's in my answer (fixed now).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Thanks Claude.

Comment: @Simon Aldworth. Rather than a general and vague question be concrete : Joint to your question an example of data.